# How to properly use mock to test methods inside the except clause

Tags: python, mocking

I have a python method which should try to call get_item_dynamodb(), but if there's a ClientError from boto3, then it should call the other 3 methods instead. I'm wondering how should I properly mock the ClientError and then test the methods inside the except clause.

```
main_method:
  try:
    get_item_dynamodb()
  except ClientError:
    start_athena_query()
    get_query_result()
    extract_info_from_result()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can [`patch`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#patch) the `get_item_dynamodb` function with a `Mock` object that has a [`side_effect`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#unittest.mock.Mock.side_effect) attribute with a value of a `ClientError` exception, so that when the `get_item_dynamodb` function is called it would raise a `ClientError` exception and enter the exception handler block.